# Unable to read kinesis data stream from Node App

Tags: nodes, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-kpl

I have setup a kinesis data stream to capture RDS changes and adding data to this stream. Data is feeding to this stream as i can see from stream dashboard. But I'm unable to create consumer, I tried KCL sample code for node but it just keep running not printing anything..

[image: incoming data]

```
import boto3
import json
import random
import calendar
import time
from datetime import datetime
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import LogicalReplicationConnection

my_stream_name = 'Foo'
kinesis_client = boto3.client('kinesis', region_name='us-east-1')
my_connection  = psycopg2.connect(
               "dbname='postgres' host='mypgdb.abcdefghijk.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' user='repluser' password='replpass'" ,
               connection_factory = LogicalReplicationConnection)
cur = my_connection.cursor()
cur.drop_replication_slot('wal2json_test_slot')
cur.create_replication_slot('wal2json_test_slot', output_plugin = 'wal2json')
cur.start_replication(slot_name = 'wal2json_test_slot', options = {'pretty-print' : 1}, decode= True)

def consume(msg):
kinesis_client.put_record(StreamName=my_stream_name, Data=json.dumps(msg.payload),     PartitionKey="default")
print (msg.payload)

cur.consume_stream(consume)
```

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client-nodejs/tree/master/samples/basic_sample/consumer

Below is my kcl implementation as provided above

```
'use strict';

var util = require('util');
var kcl = require('aws-kcl');

function recordProcessor() {
  var shardId;
  return {
initialize: function(props, completeCallback) {
  shardId = initializeInput.shardId;

  console.log('recordProcessor');
  completeCallback();
},

processRecords: function(processRecordsInput, completeCallback) {
  if (!processRecordsInput || !processRecordsInput.records) {
    completeCallback();
    return;
  }
  var records = processRecordsInput.records;
  var record, data, sequenceNumber, partitionKey;
  for (var i = 0 ; i < records.length ; ++i) {
    record = records[i];
    data = new Buffer(record.data, 'base64').toString();
    sequenceNumber = record.sequenceNumber;
    partitionKey = record.partitionKey;
    console.log(util.format('ShardID: %s, Record: %s, SeqenceNumber: %s, PartitionKey:%s', shardId, data, sequenceNumber, partitionKey));
  }
  if (!sequenceNumber) {
    completeCallback();
    return;
  }
  // If checkpointing, completeCallback should only be called once checkpoint is complete.
  processRecordsInput.checkpointer.checkpoint(sequenceNumber, function(err, sequenceNumber) {
    console.log(util.format('Checkpoint successful. ShardID: %s, SeqenceNumber: %s', shardId, sequenceNumber));
    completeCallback();
  });
},

leaseLost: function(leaseLostInput, completeCallback) {
    console.log(util.format('Lease was lost for ShardId: %s', shardId));
  completeCallback();
},

shardEnded: function(shardEndedInput, completeCallback) {
    console.log(util.format('ShardId: %s has ended. Will checkpoint now.', shardId));
  shardEndedInput.checkpointer.checkpoint(function(err) {
    completeCallback();
  });
},

shutdownRequested: function(shutdownRequestedInput, completeCallback) {
  shutdownRequestedInput.checkpointer.checkpoint(function (err) {
    completeCallback();
  });
}
  };
}

kcl(recordProcessor()).run();
```

Comment: Also tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/lifion-kinesis

Answer (score 0):

Run app with java bootstraper
../../../bin/kcl-bootstrap --java /usr/bin/java -e -p ./sample.properties